# Find date different between 2 rows in PowerBI

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerquery

```
patient_id  treatment_date
100         4/28/2018
100         4/27/2019
100         4/29/2019
100         6/22/2019
101         3/6/2021
101         1/1/2022
101         4/6/2022
102         6/2/2017
102         6/6/2018
102         10/7/2018
102         9/4/2021
102         6/2/2022
```

Hi everyone,

I have a table which recorded the date when the patients came back for treatment as shown in the data above. I want to calculate the number of days from the first treatment (first date) for their subsequent treatment for each and every patient.

[image]

The expected outcome is shown in the screenshot above in the 3rd column `days_from_first_treatment`. I'm fine with either using DAX or Power query. Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

### Edit

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column

```
VAR currenDate = CALCULATE(MAX(tbl[treatment_date]))
VAR prevDate = 
        MINX(
            CALCULATETABLE(tbl,ALLEXCEPT(tbl,tbl[patient_id]))
            ,'tbl'[treatment_date]
        )
RETURN 
    INT(currenDate-prevDate)
```

NEW solution:

```
VAR currenDate = [treatment_date]
VAR patId=[patient_id]
VAR prevDate = 
        MINX(
            FILTER(ALL(tbl),[patient_id]=patId)
            ,[treatment_date]
        )
RETURN 
    INT(currenDate-prevDate)
```

Comment: the semicolon should be a comma right?

Comment: But even I changed it the semicolon to comma, the output is a 5 digit value for all the rows

Comment: In excel it worked ). I tested it in PBI now . Please check.

Comment: Based on your latest DAX, it shows error, i attached the screenshot in my question.

Comment: I added a new solution. I can't say why the previous one didn't work it's at least strange.

Answer (score 2):

try this measure...

```
Days From First Treatment  =
VAR _first =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( 'Table'[treatment_date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[patient_id] )
    )
VAR _date =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[treatment_date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DATEDIFF ( _first, _date, DAY ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[patient_id] )
    )
```

[Sample PBix File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ayCG2flVH1NzOwJtKYl470Nnp8C63RL7/view?usp=sharing)

[image: sample]

Comment: This is a calculated measure or column?

Comment: @weizer it is a measure

Comment: @weizer mine is not working ? 

Answer (score 1):

In M you could use,

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"patient_id", Int64.Type}, {"treatment_date", type date}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"patient_id"}, {{"data", each let min=Number.From(List.Min(_[treatment_date])) in Table.AddColumn(_, "Custom", each Number.From([treatment_date])-min), type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", { "treatment_date", "Custom"}, { "treatment_date", "days_from_first_treatment"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data",{{"days_from_first_treatment", Int64.Type}, {"treatment_date", type date}})
in  #"Changed Type1"
```